# Bigger & less or smaller & more queries?

Tags: php, mysql, join

So lets say I had two tables, and one (lets call it `person`) had a field called `type` that stored an integer linking to another table (lets call it `types` with a field called `id`. What would be more performance enhancing?

- One larger query storing all the values of type and then looping over the `person` table and grabbing a value from the array we got from the `types` query.
- On every loop of `person` grab a value from `types`
- Use the `JOIN` query to join the `type` onto the `person` query.

Note: in the examples I used some fake variables such as `$db` (obviously). Just think of these like a CodeIgniter database class or something...

Example Code of BP #1:

```
<?php
    $types = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `types`")->result_array();

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `person`");

    foreach($query->result_array() as $value)
    {
        $type = $types[$value['type']];
    }
```

Example Code of BP #2: (Edited to add of form of caching)

```
<?php
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM person");

    $types = [];

    foreach($query->result_array() as $value)
    {
        if(empty($types[$value['type']]))
        {
            $types[$value['type']] = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM types WHERE id = {$value['type']} LIMIT 1")->row_array();
        }
        $type = $types[$value['type']];
    }
```

Example Code of BP #3: (NB: I haven't used `JOIN` at all so please forgive any errors in the query, and feel free to fix it up...)

```
<?php
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM person JOIN types ON person.type = types.id");

    foreach($query->result_array() as $value)
    {
        // type is already there for us in $value
    }
```

Note: `person` and `types` both (will) have over 100k+ rows, we're expecting.

Comment: 100k+ rows isn't *that* big a deal, the thing that gets me is how "types" which sounds like a normalised table can have as near as many rows as "person"?  In general, `INNER JOIN` is liable to be the most efficient method you'll find, with proper keys etc.  Your question is frankly too vague to get a real answer.

Comment: Rule of thumb: If the database can do it for you, let the database do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

The join approach (option 3) should certainly be the most efficient - the other two approaches are essentially re-inventing the processing that the database is designed to do in the first place, *and* all the relevant data has to be sent to the web server before it can be done!